# GitLab rejection flow or feature for code review

Tags: gitlab, review, merge-request

I'm wondering if it's possible to reject a Merge Request in GitLab the same way that you can approve it. What is the proper procedure for handling rejections at code review?

I have searched multiple sources and conducted some testing, but I am unsure if the rejection feature is available or if it requires a process flow with flags or a similar solution.